# Tomcat doFilter() invoked with committed response

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have a Tomcat Filter that delegates requests to the a handling object depending on the URL. This is the only filter in the `FilterChain`. I have an Ajax app that hammers this filter with lots of requests.

Recently I noticed an issue where the filter's `doFilter` method is often called with a committed response as a parameter (Internally, it is the coyote response that is marked committed).

It seems to me that the only way that this can happen is if the `recycle()` method is not called on this coyote response. I have checked to make sure that I am not keeping references to any of the request, response, outputStream, or writer objects. Additionally, I made sure to close the outputStream in a finally block. However, this doesn't resolve this issue.

This sounds like I am doing something to abuse the servlet container but I am having trouble tracking it down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tried using Tomcat 6.16 and 6.18. This is definitely is the only filter in the chain.

It seems that something is keeping a reference to the servlet outputStream. I wrapped the ServletOutputStream in my own OutputStream and then made sure the reference is destroyed. This fixed the issue so that I no longer see a committed response passed in.

This is an odd side effect of holding a reference. But I don't think it qualifies as a Tomcat bug. More likely a bug in ImageIO.createImageOutputStream() that I suspect is holding the reference.

Comment: we had to do the exact same thing. Wrap the output stream and prevent it from committing the response until we were ready.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Tomcat are you using? To me this sounds like a bug in Tomcat, I can't think of any reason why your doFilter method should be called with a response that's already been committed (if that filter is the only one in the chain, are you sure about this?).